# How can I find a template image in another image? Kinect and AForge preferred

Tags: c#, bitmap, pattern-matching, kinect, aforge

I copied the AForge-Sample from here:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/template_matching.html
And hoped, it would work with 2 Bitmaps as sources as in the following code:

```
    Bitmap findTemplate (Bitmap sourceImage, Bitmap template)
    {

    // create template matching algorithm's instance
    // (set similarity threshold to x.y%, 1.0f = 100%)
    ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching( 0.4f );
    // find all matchings with specified above similarity
    TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage( sourceImage, template ); **// "Unsupported pixel format of the source or template image." as error message**
    // highlight found matchings
    BitmapData data = sourceImage.LockBits(
        new Rectangle( 0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height ),
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, sourceImage.PixelFormat );
    foreach ( TemplateMatch m in matchings )
    {
        AForge.Imaging.Drawing.Rectangle( data, m.Rectangle, System.Drawing.Color.White );
        // do something else with matching
    }
    sourceImage.UnlockBits( data );
    return sourceImage;
    }
```

But when calling TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.P.... it gives the error mentioned above.
The template is generated this way:

```
Bitmap templatebitmap=(Bitmap)AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile("template.jpg");
```

the source is generated with the kinect-webcam, where the PlanarImage is formatted as Bitmap (method copied from somewhere, but it was working up to now)

```
 Bitmap PImageToBitmap(PlanarImage PImage)
        {
            Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(
              PImage.Width,
              PImage.Height,
              System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            BitmapData bmapdata = bmap.LockBits(
              new Rectangle(0, 0, PImage.Width,
                                   PImage.Height),
              ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
              bmap.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr ptr = bmapdata.Scan0;
            Marshal.Copy(PImage.Bits,
                         0,
                         ptr,
                         PImage.Width *
                            PImage.BytesPerPixel *
                                 PImage.Height);
            bmap.UnlockBits(bmapdata);
            return bmap;
        }
```

So, is anbody able to help me, where my mistake might be?
Or maybe anyone knows a better way to match a template with a Kinect?
The overall job is to detect a known object with the kinect, in my case a rubberduck.

Thank you in advamce.

Comment: Ok, the answer here is, that it wants Format24bppRgb-Bitmaps. Nevertheless, the result is crap anyways.Hundreds of matches with the same position and size.

Comment: I had the same problem regarding slow performance until I switch to openCV and [Emgu Wrapper](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Since the original poster is asking for a faster solution and did not receive a response, I am providing a link that will complete the required task in a fraction of the time compared to AForge. Aforge is slow because it is an iterative (brute force) method. The posters code is even slower than AForge. openCV library will do the required task extremely fast, [using a mathematical function based comparison](https://www.docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/img

Answer (score 0):

So, I just implemented it myself. But it is so slow - so if anyone has an idea to improve, feel free to criticize my code:

```
    public class Position
    {
        public int bestRow { get; set; }
        public int bestCol { get; set; }
        public double bestSAD { get; set; }
        public Position(int row, int col, double sad)
        {
            bestRow = row;
            bestCol = col;
            bestSAD = sad;
        }
    }

    Position element_position = new Position(0, 0, double.PositiveInfinity);
    Position ownSearch(Bitmap search, Bitmap template) {
        Position position = new Position(0,0,double.PositiveInfinity);
        double minSAD = double.PositiveInfinity;


        // loop through the search image
        for (int x = 0; x <= search.PhysicalDimension.Width - template.PhysicalDimension.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= search.PhysicalDimension.Height - template.PhysicalDimension.Height; y++)
            {
                position_label2.Content = "Running: X=" + x + "  Y=" + y;
                double SAD = 0.0;

                // loop through the template image
                for (int i = 0; i < template.PhysicalDimension.Width; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < template.PhysicalDimension.Height; j++)
                    {
                        int r = Math.Abs(search.GetPixel(x + i, y + j).R - template.GetPixel(i, j).R);

                        int g = Math.Abs(search.GetPixel(x + i, y + j).G - template.GetPixel(i, j).G);

                        int b = Math.Abs(search.GetPixel(x + i, y + j).B - template.GetPixel(i, j).B);

                        int a = template.GetPixel(i, j).A;

                        SAD = SAD + ((r + g + b)*a/255 );

                    }
                }
                // save the best found position 
                if (minSAD > SAD)
                {
                    minSAD = SAD;
                    // give me VALUE_MAX
                    position.bestRow = x;
                    position.bestCol = y;
                    position.bestSAD = SAD;
                }
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: for future reference, please do not use swear words in any content that you post on StackOverlfow. Your answer will be edited to remove the swearing.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution using AForge 
but it is slow take around 5 seconds but it works
As usuall u need to introduce AForge framework download and install it. 
specify using AForge namespace

and copy paste to make it work

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap sourceImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\SavedBMPs\1.jpg");
System.Drawing.Bitmap template = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\SavedBMPs\2.jpg");
// create template matching algorithm's instance
// (set similarity threshold to 92.5%)

ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.921f);
// find all matchings with specified above similarity

TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(sourceImage, template);
// highlight found matchings

BitmapData data = sourceImage.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, sourceImage.PixelFormat);
foreach (TemplateMatch m in matchings)
{

        Drawing.Rectangle(data, m.Rectangle, Color.White);

    MessageBox.Show(m.Rectangle.Location.ToString());
    // do something else with matching
}
sourceImage.UnlockBits(data);
```

Comment: I found this example too as this is just explained on the aforge-site. it simply did not do a good job. nearly every result was wrong. and 5 sec? it took some minutes for each frame. so.. no, doesnt help me. I read the documentation myself. But now, I simply introduced some other algorithm on other informations and i have 10fps.

Comment: @nico, Yes it is from the site i thought this is more simpler approach to your 4 cycling FOR statements above. So how did you solve and get 10fps ? And sorry if it doesn't help you, it doesn't have to help everybody, just newbees like me might find it useful.

Comment: I simply used 2 other features of the object. Regarding your problem: simply do a color filter and before matching prove, if in the matching area the color meets the requirements (if your object is filled red, simply try, if the middle-point meets "red"). my second feature was the depth via kinect. only if both features meet the requirements, let my slow algorithm run over these positions (not over any position as i posted it). Interesting links for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9727/Image-Processing-Lab-in-C and http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/